# How to express a required 'RETURN' statement in the grammar

Tags: antlr4

I am still a newbie to ANTLR, so sorry if I am posting an obvious question.

I have a relatively simple grammar. What I need is for the user to be able to enter something like the following:

```
if (condition)
{
    return true
}
else if (condition)
{
    return false
}
else
{
    if (condition)
    {
        return true
    }
    return false
 }
```

In my grammar below, is there a way to make sure that an error will be flagged if the input string does not contain a 'return' statement? If not, can I do it via the Listener, and if so, how?

```
grammar Evaluator;

parse
 : block EOF
 ;

block
 : statement
 ;

statement
 : return_statement
 | if_statement
 ;

return_statement
: RETURN (TRUE | FALSE)
;

if_statement
 : IF condition_block (ELSE IF condition_block)* (ELSE statement_block)?
 ;

condition_block
 : expression statement_block
 ;

statement_block
 : OBRACE block CBRACE
 ;

expression
: MINUS expression                                  #unaryMinusExpression
| NOT expression                                    #notExpression
| expression op=(MULT | DIV) expression             #multiplicationExpression
| expression op=(PLUS | MINUS) expression           #additiveExpression
| expression op=(LTEQ | GTEQ | LT | GT) expression  #relationalExpression
| expression op=(EQ | NEQ) expression               #equalityExpression
| expression AND expression                         #andExpression
| expression OR expression                          #orExpression
| atom                                              #atomExpression
;

atom
 : function                                                 #functionAtom
 | OPAR expression CPAR                                     #parenExpression
 | (INT | FLOAT)                                            #numberAtom
 | (TRUE | FALSE)                                           #booleanAtom
 | ID                                                       #idAtom
 ;

function
 : ID OPAR (parameter (',' parameter)*)? CPAR
 ;

parameter
 : expression                                               #expressionParameter
 ;

OR : '||';
AND : '&&';
EQ : '==';
NEQ : '!=';
GT : '>';
LT : '<';
GTEQ : '>=';
LTEQ : '<=';
PLUS : '+';
MINUS : '-';
MULT : '*';
DIV : '/';
NOT : '!';
OPAR : '(';
CPAR : ')';
OBRACE : '{';
CBRACE : '}';
ASSIGN : '=';

RETURN : 'return';
TRUE : 'true';
FALSE : 'false';
IF : 'if';
ELSE : 'else';

// ID either starts with a letter then followed by any number of a-zA-Z_0-9
// or starts with one or more numbers, then followed by at least one a-zA-Z_ then followed
// by any number of a-zA-Z_0-9

ID
 : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 | [0-9]+ [a-zA-Z_]+ [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ;

INT
 : [0-9]+
 ;

FLOAT
 : [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]* 
 | '.' [0-9]+
 ;

SPACE
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;

 // Anything not recognized above will be an error
ErrChar
  : .
  ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ross' answer is perfectly correct. You design your grammar to accept a certain input. If the input stream does not correspond, the parser will complain.

Allow me to rewrite your grammar like this :

```
grammar Question;

/* enforce each block to end with a return statement */

a_grammar
    :   if_statement EOF
    ;

if_statement
    :   'if' expression statement+ ( 'else' statement+ )?
    ;

statement
    :   if_statement
// other statements
    |   statement_block
    ;

statement_block
    :   '{' statement* return_statement '}'
    ;

return_statement
    :   'return' ( 'true' | 'false' )
    ;

expression // reduced to a strict minimum to answer the OP question
    :   atom
    |   atom '<=' atom
    |   '(' expression ')'
    ;

atom
    :   ID
    |   INT
    ;

ID
    : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
    | [0-9]+ [a-zA-Z_]+ [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
    ;

INT : [0-9]+ ;
WS  : [ \t\r\n] -> skip ;

 // Anything not recognized above will be an error
ErrChar
  : .
  ;
```

With the following input

```
if (a <= 7)
    {
        return true
    }
else 
    if (xyz <= 99)
    {
        return false
    }
    else incor@#!$rect
    {
        if (b <= a)
        {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```

you get these tokens

```
[@0,0:1='if',<'if'>,1:0]
[@1,3:3='(',<'('>,1:3]
[@2,4:4='a',<ID>,1:4]
[@3,6:7='<=',<'<='>,1:6]
...
[@21,82:85='else',<'else'>,10:1]
[@22,87:91='incor',<ID>,10:6]
[@23,92:92='@',<ErrChar>,10:11]
[@24,93:93='#',<ErrChar>,10:12]
[@25,94:94='!',<ErrChar>,10:13]
[@26,95:95='$',<ErrChar>,10:14]
[@27,96:99='rect',<ID>,10:15]
[@28,102:102='{',<'{'>,11:1]
...
line 10:6 mismatched input 'incor' expecting {'if', '{'}
```

If you run the test rig with the -gui option, it displays the parse tree with erroneous tokens nicely displayed in pink !

```
grun Question a_grammar -gui data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never played with the Listener before.
Via the Visitor, in the VisitStatement(StatementContext context) method, check if the **context.return_statement()**  (ReturnStatementContext) is null. If it is null, throw an exception.

Comment: For my scenario the Visitor is too late. I have an editor which uses the Parser to check the syntax before the Visit is called. If the syntax is wrong, we show the error (line and column) to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie as well.  I was thinking of forcing the lexer to barf by
requiring a return statement, so instead of:

```
statement
 : return_statement
 | if_statement
 ;
```

Which says a statement is EITHER a if_statement OR a return_statement I would try something like:

```
statement
 : (if_statement)? return_statement
 ;
```

Which (I believe), says the if_statement is optional but the return_statement MUST always occur.  But you might want to try something like:

```
block_data : statements+ return_statement;
```

Where statements could be if_statements etc, and one or more of those are allowed.

I would take everything above with a grain of salt, as I have only been working with ANTLR4 a week or so.  I have 4 .g4 files working, and am happy with ANTLR, but you may actually have more ANTLR stick time than I.

-Regards